# Can the transform axis lines be turned off?

Tags: constraints, axis, lines

Does anyone know how to disable the colored axis lines that appear when you transform an object or its components?

I find it quite distracting.

Comment: I assume you mean the green axis line that appears while you're using G > Y for instance? As far as I know that's the one overlay that you **can't** turn off. All the others can be toggled on the top-right Viewport Overlay menu.

Comment: Yes, I think that line is the same. They pop up whenever I select an axis on the gizmo. X, Y, Z for position, rotation and scale. They also pop up when transforming vertices, edges and faces. It would be great if they could be turned off like the world Axes.